# Why not set all instructions as privileged?

Tags: operating-system, switch-statement, kernel, mode

What is the main concern that we set only part of the instructions as kernel instructions?
Safety? Speed? Or something else?

Answer (score 3):

If all instructions were privileged then everything would have to run in a privileged mode and there would be no security on the system.